# cmdlet to variable not being accepted

Tags: powershell, variables, directory

Should be a very simple script but having issues getting the output from the get-aduser to be recognized as a variable, among other things. I've tried every format of quotes and brackets I can think of but can't get a proper output. The script is just querying a specific user and exporting the AD groups to a folder named for their department, then into a text file using the name and title.

```
$usertocheck = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input user to check'

$depttoadd = Get-AdUser -Filter {samAccountName -eq "$usertocheck"} -Properties Department | 
    Select-Object -expand Department

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\UserRecords\$depttoadd\"

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $usertocheck | select name | 
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\UserRecords\$($usertocheck)_$($titlelookup).txt"
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of "Any hints would be appreciated." you can ask your question clearly. i.e "How to get the output from the get-aduser cmdlet to be recognized as a variable?" or something along the lines.

Comment: Where is `$titlelookup` getting set?

Comment: I thought `$...= Get-ADUser..` should work and then referring to properties directly.

Comment: A [mcve] should include expected/deviating behaviour and also error messages you get.

Comment: so ... perhaps you could describe what is NOT working? [*frown*]

Comment: A more correct way to write the filter is `Get-AdUser -Filter "samAccountName -eq '$usertocheck'"` with that exact combination of double quotes on the outside, and single quotes around the variable. Despite what the help and online examples say, it's not a PowerShell scriptblock, and only a some combinations work without surprises. Apart from that, your code does look like it should make a folder from the department, `-Expand` is correct, and `$depttoadd` inside double quotes is correct for New-Item. Assuming the user has a Department specified in AD, and the script has filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, when I remove the quotes around $usertocheck in the below line ($usertocheck is a string already, so no need for quotes)

```
$depttoadd = Get-AdUser -Filter {samAccountName -eq $usertocheck} -Properties Department |
```

As a side note, you could also access the department property of the object returned by Get-AdUser like so

```
$depttoadd = $(Get-AdUser -Filter {samAccountName -eq $usertocheck} -Properties Department).Department
```

Acessing the properties of an object is from my experience the more reliable and cleaner way of getting the output you want, rather than using 'Select-Object'.

Hope this helps.